# Can this be a covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

$$\begin{bmatrix}10& 3& 1\\
    2& 5& 0\\
    1& 0& 2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}2& -4& 0\\
    -4& 3 &1\\
    0& 1& 2\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that above matrices cannot be a covariance matrix because first one is not symmetric and the second ones determinant is negative but any suggestions if the below one can or cannot?

$$\begin{bmatrix}10& 5& 2\\
    5& 3 &1\\
    2& 1& 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as a matrix is symmetric and [positive-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), it can be a covariance matrix. Yours appears to satisfy the conditions, so it is a covariance matrix.